# Why is the Nesterov's accelerated gradient different for convex and strongly convex functions?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

In [1405.4980](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4980), Sébastien Bubeck offered two different expressions of Nesterov's accelerated gradient (NAG) algorithm. For convex functions, he writes the following:

---

[image]

---

For strongly convex functions, he writes the following:

---

[image]

---

What would be the justification for two different forms of expressions?

This distinction doesn't seem to be enforced in many other references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, this is definitely present in other places, including Nesterov's own texts on the subject.

I'm pretty sure there's a typo in the first one; $\gamma_s$ should be $\gamma_t$. And with that typo fixed, what you see is that in the strongly convex case, the update rule for $\gamma_t$ is discarded in favor of a *fixed* value $\gamma_t \equiv \frac{1-\sqrt{\kappa}}{1+\sqrt{\kappa}}$.

You can still use the first $\gamma_t$ update rule for strongly convex functions if you want to---but the performance won't be as good. Assuming strong convexity lets you tighten things up and achieve better performance.

Note that $\kappa=\beta/\alpha$, where $\beta$ is the Lipschitz continuity constant and $\alpha$ is the strong convexity constant. So what this means is that the "stronger" the convexity, the higher the value of $\alpha$, and the closer $\gamma_t$ is to 1. This in turn means you're using less acceleration: the "optimal" first order method gets closer to standard gradient descent the more strongly convex the function is.